# Configuring state of mocked object for different scenarios

Tags: java, spring, attributes, mockito

I've a DAO and a service class. In the service class *CapService*, I've `@Autowired` a reference of DAO class *CapDAO*. The *CapDAO* class has a *private* instance field of type `int`, that has it's value injected from a properties file using `@Value` annotation.

```
class CapDAO {
    @Value("${someProperty}")
    private int expiryTime;
}

class CapService {
    @Autowired
    private CapDAO capDAO;
}
```

There is a method - `retrieveCap()` in the `CapDAO` class, which retrieves the caps from the database, based on the `expiryTime`. That method is invoked from another method in `CapService` class.

The `CapService` class uses the list returned from DAO method to create another object wrapping that list. And finally it returns that data structure.

Now, I'm testing a scenario using `Mockito` framework. I've two scenarios. In both of them, I want to invoke method of `CapService` class, which will get me the object. The list retrieved form database, will depend upon the value of `expiryTime` in the `CapDAO` class. And so will the content of the object returned by `CapService` class method.

In test, I'm invoking the method in `Service` class, and checking the value returned. Since DAO is reading `expiryTime` from properties file, both the test scenarios cannot pass with the same configured value. I've to have two differently configured `DAO` instance to be injected into `Service` class.

So, my question is - is there any way I can configure the `expiryTime` in `CapDAO` class, to create two different instance, or may be in a single instance only, and inject those in `CapService` based on scenario? No I don't have any setter for `expiryTime`. Yes, I knwo I can use reflection, but I would like to keep that as my last resort.

Comment: To clarify: one test class, two tests, each for a different value of `expiryTime`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes. I think I should move one test to a different class, should I?

Comment: Probably. You do have a test _suite_ after all. If you haven't already, check out `@DirtiesContext`, but you will still need to find an efficient way to load a different property value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis From what I read in few minutes, if I'm autowiring a bean in my test classes, then I should use `@DirtiesContext`, so that any modification to the bean instance will be reset. Am I right?

Comment: Right, depending on the `ClassMode` you use, the context will be refreshed at a particular moment, reloading all your beans. Now, you have to find a way to change the bean definitions. This is not a simple task, IMO.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok. I missed that modifying the bean will do that for the whole application. Thanks for the headsup. Anyways, I am planning to mock the bean rather than autowiring it. And then whichever method I'll use, I'll mock them. Will that be a better idea? I'll try all these possiblities, once I reach office tomorrow.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis For modification, I looked around, and all I am left with is to add setter explicitly for that. Which IMO would be better than to rely on reflection. I was only concerned, as I would not use setters in the application. But now, I have used `@Value` annotation on the setter itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48601/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

reflection is easiest possibility, you can simply use [ReflectionTestUtil](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html). Note: If you have an interface which CapDAO implements, you need also [AopUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils.html)

**Long answer**

If you don't wanna use reflection, you need separate your context and test to get this work:

```
// context1.xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test1.properties"/>
// context2.xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test2.properties"/>
```

Then you can define `someProperty` with some other value in the properties.

personally i will recommend reflection.

Comment: I thought of using `ReflectionTestUtils` rather than standard Java reflection, but then I thought it would be better to add `setters`, because the other approach is not what I would need. Thanks for your answer though.